# PHP - How to count how many months from a specific date

Tags: php

How can I count the number of months from the following two dates below using the Procedural style method?

PHP code.

```
$delete_date = "2000-01-12 08:02:39";
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date
```

Comment: Do you want the number of months *between* the two dates?

Comment: yes that is what I;m looking for

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

```
$delete_date = "2000-01-12 08:02:39";
$date_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$current_date = date($date_format);
$diff = date_diff(date_create_from_format($date_format, $delete_date), date_create());
$months = $diff->m;
```

Something along the lines of that.

Answer (score 3):

Using DateTime you will get the total months this way:

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2000-01-12 08:02:39");
$d2 = new DateTime();
$d3 = $d1->diff($d2);
$months = ($d3->y*12)+$d3->m;
```

You would still need to handle the leftover days `$d3->d` ... but that depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$delete_date = "2000-01-12 08:02:39";
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date

$diff = strtotime($current_date) - strtotime($delete_date);
$months = floor(floatval($diff) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365 / 12));
echo $months . "\n";
```

Comment: I suspect there are some edge cases where this returns the wrong value. (Each month not being 365/12 days long.)

Comment: What @middaparka says: This is likely to cause trouble e.g. in a range between February 1st and March 2nd. But then, it's not really clear how exact the OP needs this so it may be fine

Comment: Well, it all depends on the context of the problem. Is it OK to consider that there are 30 days per month or 365/12 = 30.41666 days per month? Also: Is it OK to round months count using `floor`? Or `round`? Or `ceil`?

Comment: It **really** doesn't depend on the context of the problem - the wrong answer will always be the wrong answer.

Comment: @middaparka Well, I do think it does. For example, if it is an age in months, it is OK to compute the `floor`. If it is the number of months you've been in debt, you may want to compute the `ceil` to get a pessimistic estimation on the money you have to pay. Maybe you don't even want to round the months difference but use it as offset for a comparison, including the decimals that represent the days. Can you be a bit more specific about what this months count is for and why this standard solution (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/ ) may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you looking for?

```
$delete_date = "2000-01-12 08:02:39";
$current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current date

// convert date to int
$delete_date = strtotime($delete_date);
$current_date = strtotime($current_date);

// calculate it
$diff = $delete_date - $current_date;

// convert int to time
$conv_diff = date('format', $diff);
```

Comment: I was looking for something like 1 month, 10 months 40 months and so on.

Answer (score -3):

Try this, it is easy, maybe not enogh chick, but very effective.

```
function calculateMonthsBetweenDates($fMonth, $fDay, $fYear, $tMonth, $tDay, $tYear)
{
    //Build datetime vars using month, day and year
    $dateFrom = mktime(0, 0, 0, $fMonth, $fDay, $fYear);
    $dateTo   = mktime(0, 0, 0, $tMonth, $tDay, $tYear);

    //Check dateTo is a later date than dateFrom.
    if($dateFrom<=$dateTo){
        $yearF  = date("Y", $dateFrom);
        $yearT  = date("Y", $dateTo);
        $monthF = date("m", $dateFrom);
        $monthT = date("m", $dateTo);

        //same year
        if ($yearF == $yearT)
            $months = ($monthT - $monthF);
        else{
        //different year
            $months = (12*($yearT-$yearF)-$monthF) + $monthT;
            }
        return $months;
        }
    else
       return false; //or -1
}
```

Comment: This code won´t compute correctly dates from different years.
ie. it will say that there are 11 months between Jan 1 2000 and Dec 1 2000, but it will say there are 12 months between Jan 1 2000 and Jan 1 2014!

Comment: Sorry Rosamunda, I fixed it. Now it works for any date.